# How do you go from the first step where the summation of $(1-p)^{k-1}$ transform to the fraction

Tags: probability, summation, geometric-probability

$$\sum_{k=1}^n p(1-p)^{k-1}=p \frac{1-(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)}$$

I don't know how to simplify the summation. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Use the formula $(1-x)(x^m + x^{m-1}+\dots+x+1)=1-x^{m+1}$

Comment: The key word is geometric series.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

For all $a\neq 1$, one can prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^na^k=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a},$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,lets get rid of p,which appears everywhere:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}p(1-p)^{k-1}=p\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-p)^{k-1}$

Now,lets denote $a=1-p$,where $a$ is an integer.

Now denote with $S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}$

Lets calculate the product between $a$ and $S$:

$aS=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k}$

$aS-S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k}-S$

Now lets subtract $S$ from the sum:

$(a-1)S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}$

$(a-1)S=a^n-1$

$S=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$

$S=\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}$

Now all that we have to do is to replace a with $p-1$

$S=\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)}$

$pS=p\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)}$

$p\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)}=pS=p\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-p)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}p(1-p)^{k-1}$

Hope this helps.If you have any questions,feel free to ask me.